# Problema com delay em jquery

Tags: jquery

O delay dessa função em jquery não esta pegando, queria saber o motivo, ou um outro jeito de fazer um delay no mesmo.

```
$("header").delay(1000).css("display", "none");
$(".logo_1").delay(2000).css("display", "none");
```

OBS: Já olhei todo o api do jquery esta correto como eu fiz mas não pega.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O mais simples parece-me usar o [**setTimout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) e o [**.hide()**](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) (o `.hide()` faz o mesmo que `.css('display', 'none')`):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("header").hide();
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".logo_1").hide();
}, 2000);
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fRdy4/1/)

O jQuery tem um "fila de espera" [**.queue()**](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) para poder encadear funcções. Neste caso o aspeto seria assim:

```
$("header")
    .delay(1000)
    .queue(function (next) {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
$(".logo_1")
    .delay(2000)
    .queue(function (next) {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fRdy4/)

A razão pela qual o seu código não funcionou dá para ler na página da documentação do jQuery:

> o método [**.delay()**](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) permite atrasar a execução de funções que estão numa *queue*. Pode ser usada com uma *queue* de efeitos ou uma queue customizada.

Answer (score 9):

O método `delay` só vale para animações, e esconder um elemento sem fade, somente manipulando a propriedade `display`, não envolve animação.

Um breve fadeOut deve resolver:

```
$("header").fadeOut(100);
$(".logo_1").delay(2000).fadeOut(100);
```

Ou (mesmo efeito):

```
$("header").hide(100);
$(".logo_1").delay(2000).hide(100);
```

Você verá o delay entre os dois fades. Se quer um delay no início e não houver nenhuma animação pendente antes dessas, use um `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("header").hide(100);
    $(".logo_1").delay(2000).hide(100);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: estou usando exatamente isso, ultilizo fadeIn() - delay() - fadeOut() (8 segundos) para exibir um alerta pro usuário, mas no próprio alerta, resolvi colocar um botão para o usuário dar dismiss fadeOut() no alerta, antes dos 8 segundos, más não funciona, o fadeOut só executa depois do delay(), tem como forçar a parada do delay() ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/ @hugopablo